# Why does Chrome use a font where I and l look the same?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts

In Chrome (and most other browsers from what I can tell) the font used has the issue that the glyph used for I (uppercase i) is identical to the one used for l (lowercase L)

This is something I have always wondered. Particularly when it comes to the URL-field, as this is literally inviting phishing attack. But overall I find it rather annoying that it seems to apply to whatever is the default-font on webpages as well (and if not, the majority must explicitly be changing it to a font with this issue. In which case, the "why?" applies to that question too).

PS: While it would be nice to know how to at least change it for myself (which is an easy-to-google question, and for chrome involves `chrome://settings/fonts`), this question is about the *why*, not *how to fix*. Besides, I would much rather see chrome (and other webbrowsers) fix this default for everyone, as the current state of things seems negligent in my mind.

Comment: It has to do with the choice of typography. Especially [sans-serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif) tends to get rid of little details. As such you loose the little indicator that might on a lower case L. As per the wiki article: `Sans-serif fonts have become the most prevalent for display of text on computer screens. On lower-resolution digital displays, fine details like serifs may disappear or appear too large.`

Comment: @Seth so the reason browsers pick those fonts, is a historic artifact from when they had to support low-resolution monitors? Any reason they haven't made a change in modern times (now that they can detect screen-res and go adaptive), other than laziness/inertia?

Comment: How to change font in Google Chrome https://www.technipages.com/chrome-change-font

Comment: I don't thinks this is answerable. Additionally, it's not just browsers that would have a problem. Whatever email client is showing a fishing attempt is using a certain font as well. So you might as well be asking why Outlook uses a sans-serif font in its tooltip that pops up over a hyperlink. As soon as the URL is in the browser's address bar, it's probably too late anyway, because it's very likely that it's opened already. Unless you copy-pasted it into the address bar.

Comment: There are still plenty of low resolution displays. In addition sans-serif is usually easier on the eyes (as far as I know) so it might be better for accessibility as well. Doesn't mean that there aren't sans-serif fonts that allow to distinguished those characters. Same as zero and uppercase o. Fonts probably haven't changed for legacy reasons. For example applications that rely on the standard typeface.

Comment: What's more, even with a serif font, **о** and **o** look very similar (they aren't), so using a different font wouldn't really add much, security wise

Comment: The font of the address bar (where you type URLs) is generally _not_ controlled by the browser, but by the Operating System. Your question still applies, but rather than being directed toward Mozilla, Google, _et alia_., it should be directed to Microsoft, Apple, or the producer of your Linux distro of choice.

Comment: Relevant cross-stack question: [What is a sans-serif font that still clearly differentiates similar characters?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/79090/what-is-a-sans-serif-font-that-still-clearly-differentiates-similar-characters-l)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Any browser vendor is perfectly able to override the default font settings for the address bar, if they wanted to.

Comment: @Berend - I don't see a way to do it in Chrome, IE, or Edge. (I don't have FireFox, Safari, or Opera on this computer.) The "policy" seems to be to follow the OS UI choices for the UI of the browser, but to allow the user to change the default page rendering fonts. I therefore contend that bitching to the browser manufacturer is misdirected.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  Are you a browser vendor? ;-) I didn't say *any user* is able to override the font for the address bar.

Comment: You can also specify the font (or font-family) to be used in html/css too, which the browser may allow to override the default (usually the case), so you could also ask why websites don't always specify a serif font(-family). Incidentally a lot of fonts make the zero thinner than a capital O (O vs 0), or (sometimes) add the diagonal strike or a dot in the middle to zeroes when they don't.

Comment: @Berend - No, not a browser vendor; just someone who finds it more effective to direct complaints and suggestions to the correct target. Most of the OS UI designers seem to have bought in to the theories that cause the problem in the first place; for example, Segoe UI (Microsoft's more-or-less default UI font on Windows 10) is a nice clean font, but has the _same damn problem_ with I (uppercase i) and l (lowercase L). Some of the fonts mentioned in the answer to the [ux.se] question I linked to above would be _much_ better choices for the UI elements...

Comment: @Berend - For that matter, too many of the "standard" body-text sans-serif fonts - including Verdana and Verdana Pro - have the same problem (but at least it's possible to override them).

Comment: @Smock - Slashing or dotting the zero seems to be principally a Thing in fixed-pitch fonts designed for coding or console use; most variable-width fonts seem to use the somewhat narrower zero (with the major exception being _grotesks_ in the "geometric" subclassification, such as some near-clones of AvantGarde or Futura). However, those fonts (like Georgia, but not Georgia Pro) that default to "lowercase" or "non-lining" numerals often have a problem with distinguishing zero from lower-case letter o.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm just glad this hasn't turned into a *font **vs** typeface* argument :)

Comment: @Smock - Common usage, rather than technical definitions. :) Technically, "typeface" would be more correct.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Certainly for physical implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome OS default sans-serif font is Arimo, where the small L is taller than all the uppercase letters.  This sample shows the difference.  [Chrome Arimo sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiSGc.png)

Windows assigns Arial as the default sans-serif  font for the Chrome BROWSER.  So it's not a Chrome problem, but a Microsoft  problem.  See if you can change Chrome's san-serif font to Verdana or Lucida.